# Error: There was an unknown problem while trying to parse function triggers. Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

There is an error that is occurring whenever I try to deploy my cloud functions, the strange thing here is this error shows up in windows whereas works fine in Linux, can anyone please help me sort this out? The thing is my Linux is very laggy when compared to windows, so I wanted to continue in windows, if there's any solution, please do help.
It was previously working fine, but after downloading nodejs 16.6.0 it started to act up.

The error is -

```
✖ 21 problems (0 errors, 21 warnings)
  0 errors and 2 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: There was an unknown problem while trying to parse function triggers.
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHI9o.png)

Things that I have tried are - Removing the node-modules folder from functions and then re-installing dependencies which unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Could it be line breaks?

Comment: You might want to try running your Firebase CLI commands with `--debug` flag and sharing any interesting message you see there. It's difficult to diagnose what your issue is given current details.

Comment: @jabbson Well I guess no, because previously it was working fine, without any alterations in the code itself, now it isn't.

Comment: @DanielL Any resources on how I can run Firebase CLI commands with `--debug` flag?

Comment: when you deploy the function you can use the flag --verbosity=debug or --verbosity=error to see what is going on when you deploy the function

Comment: Thank you guys, the issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

My issue is solved by downloading node v12.22.4, which may not work for everyone, but try downgrading, which might help!